# Bash script - connect to remote server and get results

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script that connects to remote server, pings other server (IP as argument) and outputs the result.

So here is what I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
# IP as argument
IP=$1
# Remote connection
ssh -p 22 pinger@tester.myserver.com
# Pinging and saving only latency results to RESULT
RESULT=`ping -i 2 -c 4 $IP | grep icmp_seq | awk '{print $7}' | cut -b 6-12`
# Outputs the result    
echo $RESULT
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Name or service not known name tester.myserver.com
```

Of course `tester.myserver.com` is just example but if I manually type that ssh command with my real remote server address it does work. So I've really no idea why this won't work as a script.

Comment: You do know that the `ssh` command will block until you exit it, and then `ping` etc. will be executed on the local machine, right?

Comment: @Biffen I am total newbie when it comes to writing bash scripts and linux commands. So what would you suggest I do/change in my script?

Comment: The internet is full of examples of how to execute commands over SSH. So I suggest you ask your favourite search engine.

Comment: @Biffen as I wrote already in my Q. I know how to execute commands over SSH. I just write ssh... connect to remote server and then execute commands there. Q is how I integrate everything in one bash script and outputs the results.

Comment: The internet is full of examples of how to execute commands over SSH *in a script* as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the usual way to send a command or list of commands to be executed on a remote server is as follows:

```
ssh user@remote.server "<your commands go here>"
```

or in your case:

```
ssh -p 22 pinger@tester.myserver.com "ping -i 2 -c 4 $IP | grep icmp_seq | awk '{print \$7}' | cut -b 6-12"
```

Notice the "\" before $7 to escape the "$". This prevents the $7 to be evaluated to a local variable $7 (which might or not be set) when you run the ssh command, keeping the $7 in the right context with the other commands.

You would still have to set $IP for it to work though, and so all together looks like this:

```
IP = $1
ssh -p 22 pinger@tester.myserver.com "ping -i 2 -c 4 $IP | grep icmp_seq | awk '{print \$7}' | cut -b 6-12"
```

Now $IP is resolved locally, while $7 is resolved remotely.

I had [a similar problem to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032409/ssh-remote-variable-assignment) when I tried to connect to a remote server to run some commands and use a local variable - just like you are doing with $IP.

Answer (score 3):

Change your corresponding line to this:

```
RESULT=`ssh pinger@tester.myserver.com "ping -i 2 -c 4 ${IP}" | grep icmp_seq | awk '{print $7}' | cut -b 6-12`
```

or without awk:

```
RESULT=`ssh pinger@tester.myserver.com "ping -i 2 -c 4 ${IP} | grep icmp_seq | sed 's/^.*time=\([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/'"`
```

regards